# ¿Cómo solventar error: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0\n at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n at XMLHttpRequest al subir archivo al servidor?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una aplicacion asp.net core con Angular y nesecito subir una imagen a el servidor

Pero me devuelve el error : Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse ()\n    at XMLHttpRequest

¿ Cómo puedo resolverlo?

TypeScript

```
 public uploadFile = (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    this.progress = 0;
    this.getParametros();

    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

this.http.post('http://chileplacercl-001-site1.itempurl.com/api/UploadFileMethod', formData, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', params: { username: this.username, identidad: this.identidad }, withCredentials: false } )
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.message = 'Exito';
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
        }
      });
  }
```

C#

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("api/UploadFileMethod")]
        public string UploadFileMethod(IFormFile file,string username,string identidad)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var p = file.FileName.Replace("_","").Split('.');
                    var name = p[0] + "_" + identidad + "." + p[1];
                    if (file.FileName.Contains(".JPG") || file.FileName.Contains(".JPEG") || file.FileName.Contains(".BMP") || file.FileName.Contains(".PNG"))
                    {
                        string path = "ClientApp/dis/assets/ProfileImageGirls/" + name;
                        if (!Directory.Exists("ClientApp/dis/assets/ProfileImageGirls"))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory("ClientApp/dis/assets/ProfileImageGirls/");
                        }
                        var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path);
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                        stream.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                        return "El archivo debe ser de tipo: (.jpg .jpeg .bmp .png)";

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.ToString(); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "El valor no puede ser nulo";
            }

            return "OK2";
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este tipo de errores se dan porque esperas como respuesta un JSON pero no es lo que obtienes, al menos no un JSON formado correctamente. Te diría que miraras lo que devuelves en realidad y si es un JSON formado correctamente o si en su defecto es un error lo que obtienes.

Comment: Si  te fijas no es lo que devuelvo, por que la llamada llega a el metodo simplemente no lo hace, el codigo de respuesta es 200

Comment: Claro, porque hay respuesta desde tu método. El problema es que tu respuesta, en tu vista, no es es un JSON que este pueda manejar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ASP.NET realmente no se como se manejara, pero normalmente por medidas de seguridad si se tiene implementada protección CSRF  cuando se hace envíos AJAX normalmente se tiene que notificar el token, es decir, cuando se hace la solicitud se debe indicar en ajax que las solicitudes llevan el token.

Por ejemplo si esto se estuviera haciendo con Jquery seria algo así:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

Como veo que te esta regresando "Unexpected token" es posible que tenga alguna relación.

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que hace referencia @gaidyjg  de que se espera como respuesta un JSON (Tenia razon).

Solucione cambiado el tipo devuelto por el metodo de string a un objeto tipo clase.

Codigo:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/UploadFileMethod")]
public RespuestaModel UploadFileMethod(IFormFile file,string identidad)
{
    var respuesta = new RespuestaModel();
    if (file != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var p = file.FileName.Replace("_","").Split('.');
            var name = p[0] + "_" + identidad + "." + p[1];
            if (file.FileName.Contains(".JPG") || file.FileName.Contains(".JPEG") || file.FileName.Contains(".BMP") || file.FileName.Contains(".PNG"))
            {
                string path = "ClientApp/dist/assets/ProfileImageGirls/" + name;
                if (!Directory.Exists("ClientApp/dist/assets/ProfileImageGirls"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("ClientApp/dist/assets/ProfileImageGirls/");
                }
                var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path);
                file.CopyTo(stream);
                stream.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                respuesta.Descripcion = "El archivo debe ser de tipo: (.jpg .jpeg .bmp .png)";
                return respuesta;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            respuesta.Descripcion = ex.ToString();
            return respuesta;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        respuesta.Descripcion = "El valor no puede ser nulo";
        return respuesta;
    }

    respuesta.Descripcion = "OK: Exito";
    return respuesta;
}
```